# Tabla Personalizada de Auditoria SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito hacer un trigger, que me inserte en una tabla auditoria, el nombre de la tabla la fecha y el tipo de accion que se realiza, este trigger debe ejecutarse a nivel base de datos luego de un UPDATE, INSERT O DELETE de cualquiera de las tablas de la BD. Hasta el momento realice esto:

```
SELECT top 1 s.name, s.type_desc, s.modify_date 
  FROM sys.objects s 
 where s.type like 'U' 
 ORDER BY S.modify_date DESC
```

Pero no me dice que tipo de modificación se hizo. ¿Me podrían dar una mano?

Comment: ¿realmente necesitas almacenar solo el nombre de la última tabla en la que se haya realizado una operación?. Pregunto porque es más fácil almacenarlas todas y luego, si necesitas solo la última, eso lo resuelves en la consulta SQL. Mantener solo un registro en esa tabla crearía un cuello de botella a nivel de base de datos.

Comment: mmmmmmmm.... podria ser, seria mejor si me dice donde se hizo la transaccion, pero, si es mucho lio, mejor hago otra cosa... que me recomendas?

Comment: Desconozco cuál es tu necesidad, no puedo realizar una recomendación con al información que se tiene a mano.

Comment: Necesito hacer un trigger, que me inserte en una tabla auditoria, el nombre de la tabla la fecha y el tipo de accion que se realiza, este trigger debe ejecutarse a nivel base de datos luego de un UPDATE, INSERT O DELETE de cualquiera de las tablas de la BD

Comment: Recomendaría entonces que edites tu pregunta, para reflejar eso (sin indicar que solo debe almacenar el nombre de la última tabla), y con gusto escribo una respuesta para que te orientes sobre como realizarlo. Por favor escribe un comentario luego de editar tu pregunta, para que me llegue una notificación. Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate ya modifique mi consulta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En SQL Server, no hay un trigger que ejecute de manera global para toda operación DML, por lo que debes escribir el o los triggers para cada una de las tablas. Voy a hacer un ejemplo escribiendo un trigger por cada operación, y solo a mencionar que podrías hacer un único trigger para las 3, pero en ese caso, debes determinar tu si se trata de un `insert`, `update`, o `delete`

Suponiendo que tienes una tabla de bitácora como esta:

```
create table BitacoraOperaciones (
   TableName sysname
 , Operacion varchar(50)
 , Fecha datetime
);
```

Y una tabla llamada `Factura` de la que quieres registra la bitácora, los triggers quedarían de esta manera:

```
create trigger trFacturaIns 
    on Factura
 after insert 
as
  insert into BitacoraOperaciones (TableName, Operacion, Fecha) values ('Factura', 'insert', getdate());
go

create trigger trFacturaUpd
    on Factura
 after update 
as
  insert into BitacoraOperaciones (TableName, Operacion, Fecha) values ('Factura', 'update', getdate());
go

create trigger trFacturaIns 
    on Factura
 after delete 
as
  insert into BitacoraOperaciones (TableName, Operacion, Fecha) values ('Factura', 'delete', getdate());
go
```

A partir de este momento, cada operación `insert`, `update` o `delete` que se realice sobre la tabla factura, dejará un registro en la tabla de bitácora.

Dado que debes repetir este proceso para todas las tablas de la base de datos (excepto la bitácora misma).

## Bonus

1. Como ya mencioné arriba, puedes escribir un único trigger por tabla, para las 3 operaciones, y valerte de las pseudo-tablas `inserted` y `deleted` para determinar la operación de la que se trata.
2. Dado que la estructura del trigger es la misma para todas las tablas, podrías valerte del diccionario de datos para generar un script SQL a partir de una consulta a la tabla `sys.Tables`, que te devuelva todas las tablas creadas por ti, algo como:

   ```
   select s.name schema_name, t.name table_name
     from sys.tables t
          inner join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    where t.type = 'U'
      and t.name != 'BitacoraOperaciones'
   ```